# How i can create dynamic sub domain in codeigniter?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have an URL structure like this;

www.domain.com/profile/12345678/BG/Sofia/my-cheap-bike

**profile**  = static 
**12345678** = member ID getting from mysql 
**BG** = Bulgaria (Country short code getting from mysql) 
**Sofia** = User's city. Selecting while creating their membership and getting from mysql. 
**my-cheap-bike** = their advertisement title. getting from mysql

I want to change this structure like this;

http://city.domain.com/profile/12345678/my-cheap-bike